# yacc fails to reduce (Python Lex-Yacc)

Tags: python, grammar, yacc, lex, ply

I'm trying to write a fairly simple grammar with [PLY (python implementation of yacc)](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/),  and am having trouble getting `yacc` to reduce strings of tokens when I want it to.

I want to interpret a series of commands that take different kinds of arguments. Each different kind of argument has a different token. The string of tokens that comes out of `lex` might look like this:

```
COMMAND VARARG VARARG STRARG
COMMAND VARARG STRARG STRARG
```

I want `yacc` to reduce each of those lines into a rule called `instruction`. However, `yacc` refuses to stop reducing the first line after the last argument (`STRARG`) and generates a syntax error because of the unexpected `COMMAND` token.

That is, instead of reducing `COMMAND VARARG VARARG STRARG` to `instruction`, `yacc` shifts one more time to get `COMMAND VARARG VARARG STRARG COMMAND` (picking up the last `COMMAND` from the next line, which shouldn't have been read).

The `yacc` portion of my code looks like this:

```
def p_rule1(p):
    r'instruction : COMMAND VARARG VARARG STRARG'

    # do stuff

def p_rule2(p):
    r'instruction : COMMAND VARARG STRARG STRARG'

    # do other stuff
```

Am I making some obvious error in my rule specifications? This is the first time I've used `lex`/`yacc`, so I wouldn't be surprised.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include additional rules for handling multiple instructions, so yacc will know what to do with that second COMMAND token. Something like below should work.

```
instructions : instructions '\n' instruction
             | instruction

instruction : COMMAND VARARG VARARG STRARG
            { do stuff }
            | COMMAND VARARG STRARG STRARG
            {do other stuff }
```

See http://luv.asn.au/overheads/lex_yacc/yacc.html#recusive

Comment: Unfortunately, when I add that rule to my code it never gets used. I think this is because it still never reduces anything to an `instruction`, and thus the `instructions` rule never sees an `instruction` on the stack. If I turn on debugging (with the new rule), the stack progress looks like: `COMMAND` -> `COMMAND VARARG` -> `COMMAND VARARG VARARG` -> `COMMAND VARARG VARARG STRARG` -> `COMMAND VARARG VARARG STRARG COMMAND` (and fails here because of the extraneous `COMMAND`). Shouldn't `yacc` have reduced `COMMAND VARARG VARARG STRARG` to an `instruction` before shifting that last `COMMAND`?

Comment: Also, the way I implemented the `instructions` rule in PLY was:
`def p_instructions( p ): r'''instructions : instructions '\n' instruction | instruction''' pass`